# logic question on inverse and equivalences

Tags: logic

Is the implication if x is even then x^2 is even equivalent to its inverse. Which is if x is odd this implies x is even.

I believe it is and have drawn a truth table to show that both implications are true on exactly the same set but in my notes it says that an implication and its inverse are not equivalent so just checking thanks.

Answer (score 0):

In that specific case, the two statements are both true. But they aren't in general: consider

$$\mbox{If $p$ is a prime $>2$, then $p$ is odd}$$ versus $$\mbox{If $p$ is odd, then $p$ is a prime $>2$}.$$